# How can I fix an error on update Google spreadsheet

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Sheet Api on PHP framework and facing error while updating sheet.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
```

How can I fix it?

```js
function add($spreadsheetId, $range, $value, $service){
    $result = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
    $numRows = $result->getValues() != null ? count($result->getValues()) : 0;
    printf("%d rows retrieved.", $numRows);
    $body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
        'values' => [$value]
    ]);
    $end = chr(65 + count($value) - 1);
    $range = $range."!A".($numRows + 1).":".$end;//ex:Sheet!A6:H
    printf("%s\n", $range);
    $result = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $body, ['valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED']);
    printf("%d cells added.\n", $result->getUpdatedCells());
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code and the request that is failing.

Comment: I've made 'add' function to update spread sheet by calling it but as I posted before,  the function doesn't work and error code occur.

Comment: Have you authenticated your app with Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had error like that.
And I solved it by downloading credential.json file again.
Additionally, Please check if spreadsheetId is correct or wrote $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS); before creating service.

Comment: Great! I've downloaded credential file again and added code you gave and the function works good. Thanks for your answer.